# Change the language of an iOS application when a button is tapped

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, localization

Is it possible to change the language of an application to Arabic by tapping on a button if the base application is in English?

I want the application language to be changed without changing the language in device and if the language is selected as arabic the text to be displayed in right to left

Comment: do some search regarding [localization](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/) ..

Answer (score 4):

1 ) First Set the Application Language by using following code

```
    case ENGLISH:
        [userDefaults setObject:@[@"en"] forKey:@"AppLanguages"];
        [userDefaults setBool:TRUE forKey:@"IS_ENGLISH"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];
        break;

    case ARABIC:
        [userDefaults setObject:@[@"ar"] forKey:@"AppLanguages"];
        [userDefaults setBool:FALSE forKey:@"IS_ENGLISH"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];
        break;
```

2) If your language code is set to English than

```
    view.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight;
```

3) If your language code is set to Arabic than

```
    view.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft;
```

Comment: can you please explain more this in detail ..? how user will be able to change language when click on button ..

Comment: On button click, call [LanguageUtility setApplicationLanguage:ARABIC]; to set language.

Comment: that's the only thing we need to do in order to change apps language ?

Comment: Will you please explain in more details am new to ios developing